# Useless isolation checks in the beginning of every transaction in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions, isolation-level

Is there any way to disable them? I am losing microseconds for doing nothing. I am sure what is the isolation lavel on my db. I don't need to check it every time.

```
2017-12-08 12:35:46.979 QUERY duration: 17 connection: 3834 resultset: 1075 message: SELECT @@session.tx_isolation
```

I use READ COMMITTED which is default on my db and is set in my `persistence.xml`

```
  <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="2"/>
```

READ_COMMITED is the default of JDBC as well and you don't need to tell Hibernate about. That's probably why Hibernate is executing the statement